# Open Webpage with Selenium and Check If Variable Is in Body

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using webdriver selenium driver to open the url in the for loop. Once the URL opens, it stores file_total_l.append(get_file_total) in a list. How can I check to make sure variable 'missing_amount' is in the webpage URL before appending get_file_total to list file_total_l?

Whats happening:

Its inserting file_total into my database a second time into my table, if I run the script twice. The missing_amount is 165,757,06 from my table so why isnt that being inserted.

print(icl_dollar_amount):

```
['627,418.07', '6,986,500.57', '165,757.06']
```

print(missing_amount[i])

```
 '165,757.06'
```

code:

```
missing_amount = []

for rps_amount2 in rps_amount_l:
    if rps_amount2 not in bpo_file_total_l:
        rps_table_q_2 = f"""select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{rps_amount2}' """
        rps_table_results = sql_server_cursor.execute(rps_table_q_2).fetchall()
        file_missing = True
        for rps in rps_table_results:
            rps_amount_f = str(rps[18]).rstrip('0')
            rps_amount_f = ("{:,}".format(float(rps_amount_f)))
            missing_amount.append(rps_amount_f)

file_total_l

for link in url_list:
    print(link)
    options = Options()
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                              executable_path=r'\\test\user$\test\Documents\driver\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get(link)
    body = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Total:')]").text
    body_l.append(body)
    icl_dollar_amount = re.findall('(?:[\£\$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)', body)[0].split('$', 1)[1]
    icl_dollar_amount_l.append(icl_dollar_amount)
if not missing_amount:
    logging.info("List is empty")
    print("List is empty")
count = 0
for i in range(len(missing_amount)):
    if missing_amount[i] in icl_dollar_amount_l:
        body = body_l[i]
        get_file_total = re.findall('(?:[\£\$\€]{1}[,\d]+.?\d*)', body)[0].split('$', 1)[1]
        file_total_l.append(get_file_total)
```

Comment: Where does `missing_amount` come from?

Comment: just edited my post. its the first section of the code. It comes from a query, i then append the resultsit to the missing_amount list.

Comment: It may just be me, but I am having trouble understanding what your processing logic is *supposed* to be. `if missing_amount[i] in icl_dollar_amount_l:` checks `missing_amount[i]` against dollar amounts found in all the URLs but then the next statement `body = body_l[i]` just processes the ith URL. A few English sentences that describe what you are trying to accomplish without even naming specific data variables would be helpful.